# How to Upgrade mysql 5.6 from 5.5.54 in web hosting

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

I want to upgrade Database server version 5.6 Now i am using 5.5.54.Anyone help me how upgrade.

Comment: If you have the right to install uninstall then why not.. and maybe you need to down your website first. But the problem is, Is version 5.6 is the need of your project? This is just an option that came from my mind.

Comment: do i need to backup all db in my hosting before Proceed to upgrade?

Comment: it's the most important.